# My javascript is not working for dom traversing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, sass, jquery-events

I'm learning Javascript and jQuery. I recently discovered about DOM Traversing, but when I'm writing the code for it, it is just not responding.
The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

</head>
<body>
<script>

$('div').onclick = function pi() {
var p = document.getElementsByClassName('.p');

p.value("hello guys");
};

</script>
<div style="background-color:blue; height:1000px; width:100%px;">
</div>
<div style="height: 600px; background-color: aqua;width: auto;">
<p style="color:black; font-size: 40px;" class="p">d
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the dot, `document.getElementsByClassName('.p')` should be `document.getElementsByClassName('p')`

Comment: theres... just so much wrong...

Comment: The amount of wrong is too damn high, and im not even meme-ing.

Comment: jquery is missing. jquery objects don't have an onclick property. to bind a click hanler, you use $('div').click(function, getElementsByClassName expects a classname, not a selector, getElemenetsByClassName returns a collection, so you've gotta either loop over it or grab the first item in the collection before alterting it, paragraph tags don't have a value, and even if they did, it wouldn't be a function,

Comment: And, you're trying to select an element that doesn't exist yet. `width:100%px;` is incorrect.

Comment: Let's also not forget the position of the script within the document as it is a self executing script it will attempt to bind elements prior to them being loaded into the DOM. Well you beat me to it :P

Comment: This looks like you tried copy pasting random bits of code from everywhere. You should go through a basic tutorial lesson and then work your way up

Comment: where's the opening html tag? lol it just keeps delivering.

Comment: Maybe this is actually a question of how many errors can we spot...

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through the problems:

1) You haven't included jQuery anywhere, so you can't use it. If you want to use it, you need to add a script tag (between the `<head>` tags given your current use) linking to it - something like:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

2) That's now how jQuery's `onclick` (which is actually `click`) works. `click` is a *function* that accepts a function. The function that you pass to `click` is executed when the user clicks on the target. Your code would be overwriting jQuery's `click`, it should instead be:

```
$('div').click(function pi() {
  // code
})
```

3) It's not forbidden or anything, but since you are already using jQuery, it doesn't make a ton of sense to fall back to native DOM fetching APIs like `getElementsByClassName`. I recommend you instead use `$('.p')`:

```
$('div').click(function pi() {
  // it's good to prefix jquery collection variables with a $
  // makes it obvious what is in them
  var $p = $('.p')
})
```

*side note* you can just use `$('p')` and query based on tag name, this avoids assigning a redundant class name

4) `.value()` is neither a jQuery method or a native method. `jQuery` has a `val()` method, but that is for setting the `value` property of input elements like `select`, `input`, etc. What you are probably wanting to do is change the text of the `p` tag. With jQuery that would be `$('p').text('new text')`. Please note that calling that will change the text for *ALL* `p` elements, or `class="p"` elements in your case:

```
$('div').click(function pi() {
   var $p = $('.p')
   $p.text('hello guys')
});
```

Hope this helps you on your way

Comment: @BenFortune thanks for pointing that out, not sure how I missed that one! Updated

Answer (score -1):

There are three mistakes I found in here.

1. Looks like you are using jQuery so insert the jQuery file in the Script tag.
2. You should not use ".p" when calling by class name.
3. A few syntax mistakes

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div').click(function(){

var p = document.getElementsByClassName('p'); //returns an Array with the class name "p"
p[0].innerHTML = "Hello Guys"; // first element of all element in "p" array

//or you could use the jquery way mentioned down below

// $('.p').html("Hello Guys"); 
 
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div style="background-color:blue; height:100px; width:100%px;">
  </div>
  <div style="height: 100px; background-color: aqua;width: auto;">
    <p style="color:black; font-size: 40px;" class="p">d</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```